# O que signifca "filho de Adão"?

Tags: significado, expressões

Na música [*O Escândalo*](https://www.letras.mus.br/renato-e-seus-bluecaps/48408/), versão brasileira de "Shame and Scandal in the Family", gravada por *Renato e Seus Bluecaps* há mais de 50 anos, há a expressão «filho de Adão»:

> Saiu da igreja
>
> De short e blusão
>
> Dizendo a todo mundo
>
> Que era filho de Adão.

O que isto quer dizer?

Comment: Talvez esteja dizendo que vai se casar com a sua irmã, não? :)

Comment: No caso "saiu da igreja", ocorreu logo após o casamento, conforme diz a canção.

Comment: Não creio tratar-se de uma expressão idiomática.  Acredito que seja apenas uma questão de rima, ou então que ele não estava ligando para a informalidade de seu traje de casamento, tal como Adão, que não usava simplesmente nada.

Comment: @tchrist, faria sentido vendo a [versão original](https://genius.com/Shawn-elliott-shame-and-scandal-in-the-family-lyrics).

Comment: @Schilive Não tem nada a ver. Foi piada sua, né?

Comment: @Lambie, na versão original, o menino se casa com quem seria sua irmã, então, faria sentido a versão brasileira (Herbert Richers) ter o menino se casando com a irmã no final e encaixaria com a expressão *filho de Adão*. Não sei se é o caso, mas me parece fazer sentido.

Comment: @Schilive Isso: "Na música O Escândalo, versão brasileira de "Shame and Scandal in the Family" **é falso**. Uma nada tem a ver com a outra. A pessoa que jogou isso no título não sabia de nada. Credo.

Comment: Eu não vou reproduzir aqui as letras inteirinhas das duas canções. Versões em outra línguas de uma música **tem a mesma melodia**.  Nem as melodias ou letras se correspondem. Credo.

Comment: @Schilive Você nem responde ao meu comentário?

Comment: @Lambie, não tinha pensado em nata útil para responder, pois, entendo pouco de música. Mas elas me parecem similares, especialmente no refrão.

Comment: @Schilive Uma não é a versão da outra. Uma versão da Garota de Ipanema em inglês é a mesma música e a mesma melodia. Todo mundo sabe isso.

Comment: @Lambie, eu não entendo de música para poder assertar por que uma melódia é diferente da outra. Não posso dizer "aqui é X-maior" e lá é "Y-mediano", se é que isto é o que conta. A música [Hurt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AHCfZTRGiI) do Johnny Cash é uma reinterpretação da música [Hurt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ty-bLdf8Bsw) do Nine Inch Nails, mas eu não conseguiria dizer que têm a mesma melodia. Vejo semelhanças.

Comment: @Schilive Será que você poderia para com isso? Me parece bobagem. Vou falar pela última vez: essas duas músicas nada tem a ver uma com a outra. O hino nacional português é uma versão do hino nacional brasileiro? E o primeiro comentário foi uma piada mal feita.

Comment: Dizer que é a versão original pode ser um equívoco, mas as músicas são claramente parecidas. Tanto no ritmo quanto na letra.

Comment: @sidney Engraçado, quando ouvi por primeira vez não era a mesma melodia. Agora parece igualzinho. Mas a letra não é parecida. Peço desculpas a todos por isso.

Answer (score -1):

Isto nada mais é que uma mensagem subliminar para usada  pelo compositor para blasfemar da fé cristã ou judaica. O próprio título da canção trás ainda mais detalhes assossiando-o ao contexto. Para o compositor, seria natural o fato de dois irmãos se casarem utilizando-se como pretexto o fato de serem filhos de Adão, o que é uma afronta a fé judaico-cristã e aos valores da família da sociedade moderna.

Comment: Obrigado e bem-vindo ao site, portuglish! Agradeço pela resposta, mas a sua resposta não tem fonte ou evidência para mostrar o que diz. Aqui no site tentamos referenciar as coisas para fortalecer o argumento. Ainda assim, obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Mas aí é que está! Pois quando se trata de uma mensagem subliminar vai de acordo com a interpretaçao de cada um. Desculpe nao poder esclarecer de forma convincente.

Comment: portuglish, não faz mal. E está muito bem-vindo ao Portuguese StackExchange!

Comment: Sua resposta podia ser mais direta - não precisa classificar a canção toda como blasfêmia ou não.